# WindowsError: [Error 193] with custom Shared Library

Tags: python, linux, windows, compilation, shared-libraries

I made a test function for a Shared library in C

```
int add(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

I compiled it using

```
gcc -fPIC -c test.c
ld -shared -soname libtest.so.1 -o libtest.so.1.0 -lc test.o
```

I tried compiling it in Windows 7, but it gave me the error `cannot find -lc`, after some several hours trying to fix this I gave up and  moved Ubuntu to compile it. Copied it back to widows and tried using it with ctypes.

```
from ctypes import *
my_library = CDLL('libtest.so.1.0')
```

But it gave me this error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

As I found out, this is error is due to the library being a 64 bit type, while I'm using python 32 bits. I installed Python 64 bits but it still gives me this error.

I also tried compiling it with -m32 and some other flags, but still give me this error

How do I compile this file?

Comment: Have you considered using MinGW?

Comment: I have it installed, but I'm always getting the cannot find -lc

Comment: That's because 1) you're not supposed to specify it in the first place, and 2) Windows doesn't use it regardless. Try `-lmsvcrt` instead.